# What information can i get from OBD II?

Tags: obd-ii, elm327

I can get the below information from `OBD II` through `ELM 327 adapter`.

- RPM
- Vehicle speed
- Engine Load
- Coolent Temperature

I would like to know what else i could get from `OBD II`.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the vehicle and what it provides, you can view a list of many possible so called PID:s [here on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs)

The PID is the id of the property you request from the bus